# Azure Data Lake Gen2 PUT authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to create a Shared Access Signature client side in my Node app. The reason being that I do not want to stream files through my app. I want the user to be able to upload a file to my Azure Data Lake Gen2 Blob Storage container directly.

I have looked at all examples I can find, but they are all server side. So I tried to generate [generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/f169ccaee02ff59d0a3589a677272d0732a59a0d/sdk/storage/storage-file-datalake/src/DataLakeSASSignatureValues.ts#L205) and use them in the PUT request. The process looks like it works and I return it to the client.

Server side:

```
async getFileUploadUrl(path) {
    const now = new Date().toUTCString();
    const startsOn = new Date(now);
    startsOn.setMinutes(startsOn.getMinutes() - 10); // Skip clock skew with server
    
    const expiresOn = new Date(now);
    expiresOn.setHours(expiresOn.getHours() + 1); // Expires in one hour

    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(this.storageAccountName, this.accountKey);

    const sas = generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters({
        fileSystemName: this.fileSystemClient.name,
        ipRange: { start: "0.0.0.0", end: "255.255.255.255" },
        expiresOn,
        protocol: SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp,
        permissions: DataLakeSASPermissions.parse("c").toString(), //  Read (r), Write (w), Delete (d), List (l), Add (a), Create (c), Update (u), Process (p)
        resourceTypes: AccountSASResourceTypes.parse("o").toString(), //  Service (s), Container (c), Object (o)
        services: AccountSASServices.parse("b").toString(), //  Blob (b), Table (t), Queue (q), File (f)
        startsOn,
        version: "2019-12-12"
    },
    sharedKeyCredential);
    


    const encodedURI = encodeURI(path);


    const filePath = `${this.fileSystemClient.url}/${encodedURI}`; 

    return {
        url: filePath,
        signature: sas.signature,
    };
}
```

Client side:

```
const { url, signature } = serverResponse;

const file = [file takes from an input tag];

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('PUT', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-date", new Date().toUTCString());
request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", '2019-12-12');
request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-blob-type", 'BlockBlob');
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `SharedKey [storageaccount]:${signature}`);

request.send(file);
```

And what I keep getting back is a 403 with the following error:

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '[signature]' is not the
> same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign:
> 'PUT\n\n\n1762213\n\nimage/png\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Thu, 24 Sep 2020
> 12:24:05 GMT\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12\n/[account name]/[container
> name]/[folder name]/image.png'.

Obviously I removed the actual signature since I have gotten it to work server side, but it looks something like this: hGhg765+NIGjhgluhuUYG686dnH90HKYFytf6= (I made this up, but it looks as if it's in the correct format).

I have also tried to return the parsed query string and used in a PUT request, but then I get errors stating there is a required header missing, and I cannot figure out which one that should be. No `Authorization` for instance should be required.

Answer (score 1):

The method `generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters` is used to create a [service sas token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas). After doing that, we can call Azure Datalake  Rest API with the sas token as the query paramater

For example

1. Create sas token with method `generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters`. When we call method `generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters`, we should define a `DataLakeSASSignatureValues`  class : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-datalake/datalakesassignaturevalues?view=azure-node-latest

```
const {
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
  generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters,
  DataLakeSASPermissions,
} = require("@azure/storage-file-datalake");

const accountName = "testadls05";
const accountKey ="";
const now = new Date().toUTCString();
const startsOn = new Date(now);
startsOn.setMinutes(startsOn.getMinutes() - 10); // Skip clock skew with server

const expiresOn = new Date(now);
expiresOn.setHours(expiresOn.getHours() + 1); // Expires in one hour

const fileSas = generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters(
  {
    fileSystemName: "test",
    pathName: "test.jpg",
    permissions: DataLakeSASPermissions.parse("racwd"),
    startsOn: startsOn,
    expiresOn: expiresOn,
  },
  new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
).toString();
console.log(fileSas);
```

2. Test ([create file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create))

```
PUT http:// https://{accountName}.{dnsSuffix}/{filesystem}/{path}
?{sas token you create in step1}

Headers:
  Content-Type:image/jpeg
  Content-Length:0
```

[image]

Comment: Made the suggested changes, still get this in the response:

`MissingRequiredHeader: An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.`

Comment: @Vhendin Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create to define your api.

Comment: @JimXu, Thank you!! I've spent hours trawling through the docs trying to figure this out. Worked perfectly for me